# Cross-Origin Request Blocked after clearing live server cache

Tags: laravel, vue.js, resources, cpanel, vite

After uploadin laravel project to cpanel and changes .env file and .htaccess I have cleared route, view, cahce, config in cpanel terminal. And then I can't load my website ,it's not visible due to this reason. This is the error throws,

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource  at http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

I have used core extension but it's not working, how to solve this?